# Correct redirect URI for Google API and OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-maps-api-3, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

I am making an application with the Google Maps API. I want to be able to have one person on a computer, watch what another person has edited to a map. I am thinking of passing information of the map to a Google Fusion Table. The other person will be able to see everything as a layer. I would like for the program to just run from the user's browser and not build a website for it.

To edit the fusion tables, I need to gain access/tokens. I am currently trying to use these there JavaScript to accomplish this. [ScriptSample.html](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/source/browse/trunk/samples/script/ScriptSample.html), [oauthWindow.html](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/source/browse/trunk/samples/script/oauthWindow.html), and [gwt-oauth2.js](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/source/browse/trunk/samples/script/gwt-oauth2.js). This is the [working example](http://gwt-oauth2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/script/ScriptSample.html).

When I run them, I get am error that says the *redirect URI* is incorrect. It says the file I use to redirect does not have authority. My first obvious question is:

> How do I give that file authority to redirect?

In my API console, I have it set up as a client-side web application. Should I change it to an installed application?

Currently I have the following settings:

- my JavaScript origin is: `https://localhost`
- redirect URI: `https://localhost/oauthWindow.html`

Thanks

Comment: Are you serious using a localhost-based callback URI? It means that the OAuth server should send the response to itself, which is meaningless. You should definitely use some URL accessible from the external network.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I have to correct myself. Callback URIs are used only to redirect your browser with the authorization result, thus a localhost-based callback URI could work in theory. On the other hand, it has serious security issues, making the whole callback URI checking method pointless. As a consequence, you still should provide an externally accessible callback.

Comment: I have issues with this as well. For some super-strange reason google has decided that my redirect url, which is `https://something` should be converted into `http://something`. This is horrible because my server have a strict requirement for ssl/https, no exceptions.

Comment: @ZólyomiIstván redirecting to localhost is how google recommends setting up the OAuth flow for installed apps.  In google's own OAuth2 library for python, this is how they implement their "flow_from_client_secrets()" method in their tools.py module.

Comment: There seems to be many misunderstandings here. Using a loopback 127.0.0.1 address is common practice for desktop apps integrating using OAuth. Obviously, the OAuth backend server will not communicate with this IP adress, but the web browser will, using client-side scripting. Meaning, on a computer, someone runs a desktop app that launches a web browser pointing to something like https://some-oauth-login-page?redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:4444. This displays the UI to log in, and after logging in, the browser will redirect to http://127.0.0.1:4444 and pass along an activation code or similar.

Answer (score 30):

There's no problem with using a localhost url for Dev work - obviously it needs to be changed when it comes to production.

You need to go here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
and then follow the link for the API Console - link's in the Basic Steps section. When you've filled out the new application form you'll be asked to provide a redirect Url. Put in the page you want to go to once access has been granted.

When forming the Google oAuth Url - you need to include the redirect url - it has to be an exact match or you'll have problems. It also needs to be UrlEncoded.

Comment: So if I want to redirect at a page hosted on local, say - localhost:9090/index.html do i give this exact url ?

Comment: then why i need to add `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback/google` and i want to go `http://localhost:3000/home` then what is `redirectUri:.....` at the spring boot application.yml file

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a loopback address for prod? There seems to be some misunderstanding here. A desktop app using Google OAuth would typically set up a HTTP listener on a port, then invoke Google's OAuth web page in a web browser, and await the redirect URI to be invoked on the local HTTP listener. This works well in prod, and is what Google recommends.