# Google API OAuth for Drive API is not working. Getting Error: origin_mismatch

Tags: oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to run the quick start code of Real Time API of Google Drive.
I believe I did everything right. But I am getting

```
Error: origin_mismatch

Request Details

    openid_connect_request=true
    cookie_policy_enforce=false
    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
    response_type=token
    access_type=online
    redirect_uri=postmessage
    proxy=oauth2relay601571239
    origin=http://127.0.0.1
    state=811328575|0.818765953
    display=page
    client_id=XXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't given much detail about your application architecture, so i can only suggest a general answer. OAuth restricts which URLs can be referred to it. The list of permitted URLs is configured in the API console at https://code.google.com/apis/console. The URL is very fussy, so make sure you enter it exactly as it appears in the address bar.

As at Oct 2013, you can't use localhost. You have 2 choices.

1. edit 127.0.0.1 = mydevserver.example.com into your /etc/hosts
2. use a url shortener (eg. goo.gl) to create an alias to localhost

However, I believe that it is now possible to configure localhost in the 
Google  api console.

Comment: I am trying to run the quick start code of Real Time API of Google Drive given at following link:
https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart

I think that I am getting error because I am using localhost as redirect URI and JS Origin. But some links on Stack Overflow says localhost can be used.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330919/correct-redirect-uri-for-google-api-and-oauth-2-0
Please tell me if you need any other detaail about my problem.

Comment: You can't use localhost.  You have 2 choices. (1) edit 127.0.0.1 = mydevserver.example.com into your /etc/hosts , (2) use a url shortener (eg. goo.gl) to create an alias to localhost

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used 1st option and it worked for me. 2nd optiont did not work rather. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rahul can you tell me how you did it? As I can't do it, what I'm doing is going to c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file and writing 127.0.0.1:4200  www.e.com

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri /etc/hosts in Android we are talking about. Not in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with origin_mismatch.

From: [Create a client ID section](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js) localhost should work and worked for me after small testing.

Origin in Google API i have:http://localhost
URL to address bar in browser:localhost

From the beginning this configuration not works, but after i tried write to address bar: 127.0.0.1->enter->origin_mismatch, it's correct and after again write localhost, now it's works.

Tested same behaviour in Firefox 39 and Google Chrome 37.0.2062.120 Ubuntu 12.04 (281580) (64-bit).