# Google calendar Add Event In ASP .net : Auth fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-calendar-api

In my asp.net core app I'm going to add new event to google calendar. But it showing error in google. I have enabled calendar api and insert ClientId and ClientSecret. But it showing error.

[image]

This is my code below.
[image]
and
[image]

```
   public void CreateEvent(string email, string text)
    {
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        new ClientSecrets
                        {
                            ClientId = "461480317556-xxxxxxxxxxg.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                            ClientSecret = "RljgIL79D2YFkmVaWQypCjIa",
                        },
                        new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },"user",CancellationToken.None).Result;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
        });

        Event myEvent = new Event
        {
            Summary = "Appointment",
            Location = "Somewhere",
            Start = new EventDateTime()
            {
                DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 6, 2, 10, 0, 0),
                TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            End = new EventDateTime()
            {
                DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 6, 2, 10, 30, 0),
                TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO" },Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>(){new EventAttendee() { Email = email } }
        };

        Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(myEvent, "primary").Execute();

    }
```

Comment: the error is saying the URL you're using isn't one which is registered for use with that client secret. AFAIK you can't use localhost for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19296805/5947043 may be informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved issue my self.Problem was I have put type as "Web Application" Instead of "other".. After I changed it to type as "other" It worked.

[image]