# how to fix google OAuth2 error?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

the error shows are

The JavaScript origin in the request, http://localhost, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/MY_CLIENT_ID?project=810656699155 to update the authorized JavaScript origins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330919/correct-redirect-uri-for-google-api-and-oauth-2-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct redirect URI for Google API and oauth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330919/correct-redirect-uri-for-google-api-and-oauth-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your configuration in the google developer console. You need to specify a whitelist of JavaScript origins, which are allowed to access the OAuth end point. You should be able to add localhost to this whitelist, und the link showed in the google developers OAuth settings.

For security reasons, you should not activate this in a production environment, because you do not want to run the OAuth process locally on your machine. But this is completly fine in development environment.