# Getting login and redirect issues from Google

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-developers-console, next-auth

Trying to set up an Authentication for my app, and all seemed to be working correctly, but when I tried testing it out I got this error message

> Authorization Error
> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/$%7Byour_client_id%7D?project=$%7Byour_project_number%7D)

Can you point me in the right direction to fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Is a configuration issue.  The redirect uri is used to return the authorization code to your application after the user has consented to your applications access to your data.  You have created a web client credentials up on Google developer console.

What you need to do is go back there and add a Redirect uri of

```
 http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google
```

It must match exactly don't add any spaces at the end or anything.

If you have any issues i have a video which will show you exactly how to add it [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a mismatch with the `Authorized redirect URIs`. 
Are you sure you have entered the correct URIs? 
Redirect URI should be the URL that you'll be redirecting the user to after the login page or the base URL of your application Eg: `https://localhost:8000`

Also, make sure that you are using the correct `Client ID` and `Client secret`

Similar Questions

1. [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)
2. [Correct redirect URI for Google API and OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330919/correct-redirect-uri-for-google-api-and-oauth-2-0)

Comment: client id and client secret have nothing to do with this error message.  Are you really linking answers that are ten years old?