# What should my URI be for Google Cloud API

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, google-api-python-client

I would like to send emails using the Gmail API from a python script I have on my computer.

Here is the code I have so far:

`test.py`

```py
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret.json',scopes=['email'], redirect_uri='http://localhost/authorize/')
flow.run_local_server()
```

When I execute this, it redirects me to a separate url shows this

[image: IMG]

My understanding of this problem is that I need to have a `redirect uri` that matches one on my google cloud platform dashboard for this app. The only thing is I just want to run this locally so I placed the uri `http://localhost/authorize` instead.

To confirm, I did add `http://localhost/authorize` to my `redirect uri` on the Google Cloud Platform.

I referenced this answer I found but could not find my solution:
[Correct redirect URI for Google API and OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330919/correct-redirect-uri-for-google-api-and-oauth-2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I needed a Redirect URI because I made the OAuth2 Key for a Web App rather than a Desktop App. In this case, a redirect uri is not needed.