# How to solve Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch while integrating social login in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0

I tried to integrate Google Social login in a WordPress website but it shows the following error:

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.

I am not sure what URL to keep in redirect URI. Can you please help?

Comment: Redirect URI is the point to which the response will be sent and displayed once the OAuth authentication is completed. Usually for Dev work or testing, it is common to use the localhost itself but once being deployed to production, the host should be something that can be accessed from external network.

Review this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330919/correct-redirect-uri-for-google-api-and-oauth-2-0

Answer (score 0):

double check the redirect URI
it should in this form

```
yourwebsite.com/wp-login.php?loginSocial=google
```

but depends on the plugin used there maybe some difference in the URL